# Call to undefined function _deprecated_file() in class-smtp.php

Tags: hosting, smtp, deprecation

I have moved two wordpress sites from a hosting provider to my own VPS with plesk. The status given by the wordpress toolkit plugin of plesk is "broken. When I look at the error details the following error trace is given:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function _deprecated_file() in /var/www/vhosts/add2bim.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-smtp.php:6 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1251) : eval()'d code(100): require_once() #1 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1251): eval() #2 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1212): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress() #3 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(23): WP_CLI\Runner->start() #4 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(77): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process() #5 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(27): WP_CLI\bootstrap() #6 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/boot-fs.php(17): require_once('...') #7 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/wpt-wp-cli.php(31): require_once('...') #8 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/add2bim.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-smtp.php on line 6 Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function _deprecated_file() in /var/www/vhosts/add2bim.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-smtp.php:6 Stack trace: #0 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1251) : eval()'d code(100): require_once() #1 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1251): eval() #2 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Runner.php(1212): WP_CLI\Runner->load_wordpress() #3 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/WP_CLI/Bootstrap/LaunchRunner.php(23): WP_CLI\Runner->start() #4 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/bootstrap.php(77): WP_CLI\Bootstrap\LaunchRunner->process() #5 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/wp-cli.php(27): WP_CLI\bootstrap() #6 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/php/boot-fs.php(17): require_once('...') #7 /usr/local/psa/admin/plib/modules/wp-toolkit/vendor/wp-cli/wpt-wp-cli.php(31): require_once('...') #8 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/add2bim.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-smtp.php on line 6
```

What is going wrong? Below is the class-smtp.php file:

```
<?php

/**
 * The SMTP class has been moved to the wp-includes/PHPMailer subdirectory and now uses the PHPMailer\PHPMailer namespace.
 */
_deprecated_file(
    basename( __FILE__ ),
    '5.5.0',
    WPINC . '/PHPMailer/SMTP.php',
    __( 'The SMTP class has been moved to the wp-includes/PHPMailer subdirectory and now uses the PHPMailer\PHPMailer namespace.' )
);

require_once __DIR__ . '/PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

class_alias( PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP::class, 'SMTP' );
```

I understand that the function "_deprecated_file()"does not exist, but I don't know if it's suppost to exist? Where should it exist? And why doesn't it exist?

thanks in advance

Comment: [The function should exist](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_deprecated_file/). Can you make sure that all files were moved completely? You can also try to overwrite wp-includes/* files with official ones

Comment: are you sure you have a fully intact WordPress install? Delete and restore your `wp-admin` and `wp-includes` folders using a fresh copy of WordPress

Comment: I got something like that message when tried to start WordPress under PHP 8 a few months ago.